# How to turn off automatic android emojis?

Tags: emoticons

When I type in :-) or <3 into my messages app on my galaxy s8, it changes the text into these dumb green android emoticons. How do I turn this off so that it displays the actual '<3', ':-)', etc instead of these dumb green android emoji's??[image]

Comment: Do you have a different keyboard installed, rather than Samsung's default? I could see this as being a function of auto-replace, but I don't see it in the default keyboard.